How are challenge bosses in the keep scaled?
The menu of boss fights available to me in the Keep are always all the same level, and that level increases as I progress in the game.  I'm trying to figure out when it makes the most sense to grind for 5-stars in each fight, given this.  I haven't been able to isolate the exact formula for the boss' levels, however.  My best guess candidates thusfar are:

They're simply 3 levels higher than the highest level monster you've trained.
There's discrete breakpoints where the boss' levels are incremented based on monsters you own crossing certain thresholds.
They're leveled up whenever certain quests are completed, champions defeated, or rooms are added to the map.

